# Invertible matrices over $Z_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let C be an invertible matrix of size $10 \times 10$ with coefficients over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Why is C also an invertible matrix over the rings $\mathbb{Z}_{4},\mathbb{Z}_{8}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me rephrase:

> Let $C$ be a matrix with integer entries. If $C$ is invertible mod $2$, is $C$ also invertible mod $4$ and mod $8$?

Now, $C$ is invertible mod $m$ iff $\det C$ is invertible mod $m$.

In particular, $C$ is invertible mod $2$ iff $\det C$ is odd. And this is exactly the condition for $C$ being invertible mod $4$ and mod $8$.